# What 'commands' are supported by the %% escape prefix in Google Cloud Datalab?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab

I have seen in the Google Cloud Datalab documentation that the '%%' escape sequence is used to execute something other than Python. So far I have seen:

`%%bash` for executing arbitrary commands in the shell

`%%sql` for executing a BigQuery query

`%%chart` for displaying the data with Google Charts.

I haven't yet found a list of all the possible commands that are supported with the double percentage sign escape sequence. Does one exist? If not, can anyone supply me with a fuller list at least?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of standard ones documented at http://ipython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/interactive/magics.html as well as %%bigquery, %%sql, %%chart and %%storage. You can use --help with each of the latter four to get help on the available subcommands.